# Incorrect installation of llvm from source with homebrew?

Tags: llvm, homebrew, clang++, llvm-clang

I wanted to use new features of clang so I installed llvm (with the tooling) using `brew install llvm`. I was surprised because the installation took so little amount of time which was because `brew info llvm` reveals that I installed the bottled version `llvm: stable 4.0.0 (bottled), HEAD [keg-only]`.

For whatever reason, I wanted to build llvm from source. I then proceed to use `brew rm llvm` and `brew install --build-from-source llvm` in sequence. Now I figured that I had uninstalled the pre-built binaries I installed with the initial `brew install llvm` command and build completely new llvm from source with `brew install --build-from-source llvm`.

After these commands, it boggles me that `brew info llvm` still shows `llvm: stable 4.0.0 (bottled), HEAD [keg-only]` the bottled installation. Did I totally mess up? Are the llvm executables installed in `/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin` the pre-built ones (or did `brew rm llvm` remove them?) or the new I build from source? Is there a possibility that I now have two conflicting installations of llvm?

Comment: Do you not show the "Built from source on YYYY-MM-DD..." and the command line options you gave it when you do `brew info llvm`?

Comment: `brew info llvm` shows `Built from source on 2017-03-24 at 10:53:29` which corresponds to the time I installed via `brew install --build-from-source llvm`. If I would have just used `brew install llvm` I guess it wouldn't say _Built from source_?. I guess I'm only confused that at the top of the info it specifies `llvm: stable 4.0.0 (bottled), HEAD [keg-only]` the bottled version...

Comment: I agree with the confusion however I just went through what you went through and it did go through the cmake/make/build process on my machine. Took about 20 mins on my Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line of `brew info llvm` is not relevant to your installation method.

For example, the first few lines of my `brew info git` (I installed one from source):

```
git: stable 2.12.2 (bottled), HEAD
Distributed revision control system
https://git-scm.com
/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.11.1 (1,456 files, 32.4MB)
  Built from source on 2017-02-03 at 23:07:01 with: --with-blk-sha1
/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.12.0 (1,452 files, 32.9MB)
  Built from source on 2017-02-27 at 04:22:05 with: --with-blk-sha1
/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.12.2 (1,454 files, 32.9MB) *
  Built from source on 2017-03-26 at 02:11:02 with: --with-blk-sha1
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/git.rb
```

The version which postfixed with `*` is currently used, or linked to `/usr/local/opt/`.